# Oracle SQL condition in range of dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I need a Oracle SQL query to get all the rows that respect this condition:
I have a table in which there are products with a start date of validity and an end date of validity. In input I have a range of date (ex. 20170530 and 20170630). I would get all the products that are valid in the given range. Thank you

**Edit:**
You are right, I try to be more clear with an example.
I have a table PRODUCTS in which I have two fields: START_DATE and END_DATE (yyyymmdd)

```
PRODUCTS
----------------------------
|id | start_date | end_date |
----------------------------
|1  | 20170101   | 20171230 |
|2  | 20170501   | 20170705 |
|3  | 20170101   | 20170501 |
|4  | 20170601   | 20170620 |
|5  | 20171010   | 20171110 |
|6  | 20170110   | 20170610 |
```

I would to extract all the products that are valid in the range 20170530-20170630. It means that the validity of the product must be in the given range 20170530-20170630.
So, from the table above, i will extract products with id

```
1 
2
4
6
```

Thank you

** SOLVED Edit 2 **
Ok, what I wanted is to get rows in which the dates overlap the input range of data given as parameter. To do so, there is a simple query:

```
(StartDate1 <= EndDate2) and (StartDate2 <= EndDate1)
```

Comment: I need you to read [How to ask a good question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: what have yo done so far? what is your SQL?

Comment: It will be more helpful to answer if you clarify how do you define a `valid` product ? What conditions your product should satisfy to be valid in terms of date range ?

Comment: There are two date ranges, the products date range and the input date range. They can be distinct, overlap or one covering the other fully. In which cases do you consider a product valid in the given range? It might be best to make up a sample table for all cases and show the expected result.

Comment: Why are you (or your organization) storing dates in the VARCHAR2 data type? They should be DATE data type. There are at least 100 very good reasons for that.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear, but here is my interpretation of it. You have a table such as this:

[Figure 1: My Product Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LP1cy.png)

If you want all products that are valid for the range: 09/07/2017 to 11/07/2017 then you would expect ITEM 1 and ITEM 2 to be returned. The SQL Query would look something like this:

> **SELECT**     *
>
> **FROM**   MY_PRODUCT_TABLE
>
> **WHERE**  *MY_START_DATE* **BETWEEN** START_DATE  **AND** END_DATE
>
> **AND**    *MY_END_DATE*   **BETWEEN** START_DATE  **AND** END_DATE

Remember the BETWEEN function is inclusive, meaning it takes values between the START_DATE and END_DATE into consideration as well.

**Note**: If you are using string variables as input, it would be wise to use the TO_DATE function (i.e. TO_DATE (MY_START_DATE, ‘DD.MM.YYYY’) etc. depending on format entered.